# Django rest framework queryset gives me .pk i want .name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my model

```
class Vacatures(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my .view

```
 class VacaturesOverzichtMobile(generics.ListAPIView):
        model = Vacatures
        serializer_class = VacaturesSerializer
        queryset = Vacatures.objects.all()
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = Vacatures.objects.all()
            return queryset
```

So in the model there is `Employer` as foreign key. The api call in the view is working fine. The only thing is I get the employer as employer.pk , but I want the name of the `Employer` which is in the `Employers` model.
Can I tune the queryset so that it returns `employer.name` instead of employer.pk

Comment: add to your `VacaturesSerializer`: `employer = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='employer.name')`

Comment: ok i will try that, but can you explain what iam doing here? because employer already is in Vacatures model.

Comment: The foreign key field stores id. So we are telling to serializer to grab name instead of id.

Comment: ok i understand, but the Employer  class has a name = Charfield(....) in it.
Can i just do Employer.name ? this doesnt exits, or am i wrong. I have to get an object of Employer first or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with serializers for both models of the relationship as described in the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Then you have full control over which attributes of `Employer` you want to include. This approach is called "serializers as fields" in DRF.

```
class EmployerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employer
        fields = ['name']

class VacaturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employer = EmployerSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vacatures
        fields = ['title']
```

Comment: tx this makes sence, i will test it out. However when i do need the .pk i get only the name. Am i right ? or just tune fields = ['name', 'pk'].

Comment: Yes correct if you also need the primary key (`pk`) then you would simply adapt the fields to be `['name', 'pk']`.

Comment: ok, i follow it. But how to implement both serializers in my listview api, see my code above

Comment: You need to specify `serializer_class` in your view, see also the [DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview). But I can see you already have `serializer_class = VacaturesSerializer` in there so it's just a matter of adding the serializer class definitions.

Comment: yes, but in your example i need to implement 2 serializer_classes, as far as i know this isnt possible

Comment: `EmployerSerializer` is only referenced in `VacaturesSerializer`. See the line `employer = EmployerSerializer`. So you basically just change your `VacaturesSerializer` and in your view `serializer_class = VacaturesSerializer` stays the same.

Comment: tx iam getting it and wil test your solution